# Nullified terms of this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, computer-algebra-systems

This the polynomial:

$6 + 3x - 5y + 7xy -8x^2 + 3y^2 + 4x^2y - 7xy^2 + 9x^3 - 5x^4 + 8y^4x$

I would like to know which terms are there (so that I will form the complete polynomial, with zero as a coefficient for these terms).

For example, in this polynomial:

$-5 + y + 9x + yx^2$

I know that the "complete" polynomial is:

$-5 + y + 9x + 0xy + 0x^2 + yx^2$

Notice how the "complete" polynomial bounds the "hidden" terms by its "max" term.

Comment: This seems to be a question about a particular CAS, but you didn't say which one.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by complete. In your last example, why do you not include $0 y^2, 0 y^3, 0 y^2 x$, etc?

Comment: No it's not @RobertIsrael, we have a school project where we try to build one.

Comment: You could collect all terms $x^i y^j$ where $i+j \le n$.

Comment: @copper.hat fair question. I updated my question.

Comment: Yes @copper.hat, bravo! That comment should be moved in the answers section!

Comment: Why I got downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are terms $x^i y^j$ where $i \le n_x, j \le n_y$ then there
are a total of $(n_x+1)(n_y+1)$ terms.

Comment: I am still having issues on finding the terms in the polynomial I posted. There should 25 terms in total, right?

Comment: Correct, $n_x=n_y=4$, so there should be a term for each of the $x^iy^j$s.

Comment: OK, I failed to find them all, can you please help? Here is what I have till now: $6 + 3x - 5y + 7xy + 8x^2 + 3y^2 + 4x^2y - 7xy^2 + 9x^3 + 0y^3 + 0x^3y + 0xy^3 - 5x^4 + 0y^4 + 0x^4y + 8xy^4$.

Comment: It really is a matter of just drawing a $5 \times 5 $ table. The missing terms are $x^3y^2, x^3 y^3, x^3 y^4$, $x^4y, x^4 y^2, x^4 y^3, x^4y^4$, $x y^4$, $x^2 y^4$.

Comment: Oh that's clever. A matrix where the rows are going to be $x^0, ..., x^4$ and the columns $y^0, ..., y^4$. Then, every cell will represent a term, right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Do you know why I got downvoted?

Comment: @gsamaras: I have no idea. I try to ignore downvotes (not very successfully).

Answer (score 1):

copper.hat's answer is very reasonable (and in particular matches your example of total degree 3).

But be careful - there are other, very sound systems. The "true" answer is: "it depends". More precisely, which terms are missing depends on the monomial order of your underlying polynomial ring, which for many applications is irrelevant and, thus, unspecified. Also, for some (many) standard monomial orders, it could well be infinitely many terms.

If I want to stress the fact that the polynomial is, say, quadratic in $x$ and linear in $y$, like in your template, I'd use the $i\le n_x, j \le n_y$ rule as proposed, but also order the terms and parenthesise as $$x^2 (a_{21}y+a_{20}) + x (a_{11}y + a_{10}) + a_{00}$$ for clarity and to make sure that my intentions come across.

Otherwise -- and in particular for a rather dense polynomial -- my natural choice would be not to use any terms where the total degree of the monomial exceeds the *total degree* of the original polynomial, and I'd order the terms by total degree and, in case of ties, lexicographically.
In your example, the total degree is 5, and I would fill in all $x^iy^j$ with $i+j \le 5$, as in copper.hat's comment - that's only 21 instead of 25 terms.

Comment: Thank you, interesting answer!! How come that I got two good answers in a -1 question? ;p

Comment: I guess a numerics person would say: even ill-posed problems have to be solved somehow, and a little bit of perturbation or the choice of the boundary conditions can change the solution entirely... ;-) The reason for the downvotes could be that you question leaves some room for interpretation; on the other hand, once you have the full specification of how the "complete" polynomial should look like, that will essentially be the solution already.

Comment: Well @akobel, that's why I asked. Nice comment!